# 250-350 MHz voltage controlled oscillator

Tags: oscillator, circuit-design

I need to build a 250-350 MHz voltage controlled oscillator.

I have been checking out ring oscillators but they cannot reach these frequencies (max ~20 MHz).

Thus, I would like to know which are the usual designs for the range between 250-350 MHz. I suppose the best solution is a Colpitts oscillator, nevertheless I am not pretty sure if they are the only solution.

Some IC oscillator also would do the trick.

Comment: Maxim has several VCOs that work in this range, for example, a quick Mouser search reveals: http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Maxim-Integrated/MAX2608EUT+T/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuuBt6TL7D%2f6FqU99%252bQUcYj

Comment: What are your oscillator requirements? 300MHz \$\pm10\$ppm is very very different from a 250-350MHz VCO. Currently, the question is too broad, covering *all* oscillators that operate in this frequency range.

Comment: Thank you for the point. I've just edited the question to be clearer. I mean a VCO between 250~350 MHz.

Comment: do you really need a VCO or wouldn't you also be happy with a complete synthesizer

Comment: @MarcusMüller What do yo mean with a synthesizer? What I understand is to create a sinus with a memory and a microprocessor, like in a FPGA. Or do you mean there exist IC with this functionality?

Comment: @RubénSánchez indeed, there is! Google for "fractional-N synthesizer". They take one reference oscillator (let's say 10 MHz) as input, and can generate a giant set of output frequencies. I know of devices that use fractional-N to generate the "rough" LO frequency, and then simply multiply the signal with a \$e^{j2\pi f_\text{offset}n}\$ to make it possible to generate **any** arbitrary frequency.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you won't get a giant set of sinewave output frequencies without changing component values manually. Sinewave VCOs tend to be limited to a 2:1 range.

Comment: @Andyaka not true. The synths I know span e.g. 50 MHz to 2.2 GHz without much ado. Of course, the microwave design for the resulting signal is not that trivial to do "broadband enough".

Comment: @MarcusMüller then they might be using a sequence of multiple VCOs to cover the full range - are you sure they are sine wave output?

Comment: @Andyaka http://files.ettus.com/schematics/wbx/WBX.pdf p.3, the ADF4350.  Directly used for mixing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The ADF4350 only has a 2:1 range on the internal VCO then it uses digital dividers (hence non sinewave) outputs for the other ranges. Does the ADL5387 RX mixer take the non-sine wave input for its local oscillator with grace I wonder?

Comment: @Andyaka aaah true: the ALD5387 LO input digitally divides the input, so yeah, obviously, it takes square waves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinewave oscillators at this sort of frequency tend to be the colpitts type oscillator because it is easily tuned with a vactor diode. This is the general idea: -

[image]

The varactor can change capacitance maybe by a factor of 6:1 and this results in a change of frequency that is \$\sqrt6 :1\$ (2.45:1). This then becomes a voltage controlled oscillator (VCO).

You can hang a PLL around it like the ADF4111 like this: -

[image]

Notice the VCO shown as a block top right. I've used this sort of design quite successfully at frequencies between 100 MHz and 600 MHz but the tuning range is only a bit over 2:1.

If you want wider than 2:1 there is a design on the net that uses a varactor and also tunes the inductor by varying the permeability of the inductor core by using DC current. You can get maybe 7:1 (frequency range) from this and I have been considering it: -

[image]

Or if you want a bigger range, go for a dual VCO method and a mixer. Set one VCO to tune from (say) 600 MHz to 800 MHz and another VCO to fall from 600 MHz to 400 MHz - mix the two outputs (balanced modulator) and after filtering you can get a frequency from the low MHz up to maybe 400 MHz. You need to have quite stable VCOs or use a couple of VCO control loops to keep basic frequency stability reasonably good.

You don't need two VCOs because you can mix a fixed frequency with a variable frequency to get a decent range but filtering is harder if you want sinewave purity. With two VCOs spanning in opposite directions the sum frequency is always constant (1200 MHz in the above example) and a notch filter can pretty much eradicate this unwanted product in the mix.

One word: it's never as easy as it sounds! A lot of care and attention to detail is required to get good performance.