# Which Is Preferable For Changing Oscillation Frequency ? Changing Capacitor Or Inductor Value?

Tags: frequency, circuit-design

I Want to make a Frequency generator,which generate frequency 900MHz,2100MHz and 2300MHz.

I fixed my capacitor value is 15pf.

Now my question is can i buy variable inductor?

and Which is Preferable method to change my frequency ?

and cheap method ? i change my capacitor value or inductor value.

and which type capacitor i used ?

Comment: They're both terrible. Use a PLL.

Comment: A variable capacitor is a way more common component than variable inductor (which I've personally never seen)...

Comment: PLL means ? and which range capacitor i used

Comment: PLL=Phase Locked Loop - http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/what-are-abbreviations-used-in-electrical-engineering

Comment: hello...please say  which is effective way to change frequency ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Here you go! http://www.radiomuseum.org/r/federal_ra_variometer_no_90.html Just turn the knob. As the inner coil rotates, its field partially adds or cancels the outer coil. Q is pretty atrocious at minimum inductance, obviously, so they barely survived the 1920s... Or http://www.crystalradio.net/crystalsets/hassell/index.shtml - scaling this to 2GHz is left as an exercise :-)

Comment: What sort of stability do you require?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but you need to learn much more before you try to build this. You obviously have no experience, and you are trying for something far beyond your level of competence. Start low. Try building an oscillator at 900 Hz. Then increase by a factor of 10. Keep on with this. You will need to learn different techniques along the way, and GHz construction techniques are something which will come as a surprise. You are setting yourself up for major disappointment if you try to do what you are doing with no knowledge.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, and how will you make a PLL without a VCO? Or a VCO without a variable capacitor or inductor?

Comment: @miteshgandhi, making a VCO that spans more than 2:1 between its minimum and maximum frequencies is not easy. You won't find many commercial products to do this for a reason. Your application might be better served by just building three fixed-frequency oscillators and switching between them.

Comment: A varactor oscillator solution that can be tuned from 900MHz to 1.2 GHz might be easiest; you can frequency-double that with an off-the-shelf mixer to get the higher frequencies you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a varactor diode, which would allow you to embed the resulting VCO (voltage-controlled oscillator) in a PLL (phase-locked loop) as @Ignacio recommends.

A varactor diode (aka [varicap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap)) acts as a voltage-controlled capacitor.

Comment: which type varactor diode i used for range 900MHz to 2300MHz

Comment: Try Skyworks products.

Comment: @miteshgandhi - Spehro forgot to mention that you cannot simply substitute a varactor for a capacitor. You will need to do some study to learn how to use a varactor.

Comment: i know only one equation to change the frequency : 1/2*pi*sqrtLC

Comment: As @WhatRoughBeast says, there are some subtle things (like the capacitance will vary with the signal voltage causing harmonics) and of course you have to isolate  it with a series capacitor and a large value resistor so that a bias voltage can appear across it.

Comment: by changing capacitor or inductor we change frequency .

Comment: Change voltage => capacitance changes.

Comment: so, i keep fixed value of capacitor and inductor and change only value of voltage

Comment: No, you are using a capacitor that has its value controlled by applied voltage - the varacter diode.

Comment: @miteshgandhi - Please. Just stop. You don't know what you're doing, and the suggestions you receive don't make any sense to you. Try to find someone you can talk to who has done something like this, or find a detailed set of instructions on the web. You need to learn a lot of stuff like RF construction techniques, and you'll need to buy some test gear. Don't just go charging into this, thinking that you can fake it. You can't. The universe is not your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [**this**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241352/250-350-mhz-voltage-controlled-oscillator?noredirect=1#comment527053_241352) answer given recently to a question about oscilators operating about 300 MHz. The same principles are also involved at UHF frequencies.

Given that you haven't said you wanted a sinewave I will also propose this: -

[image]

The ADF4350 has an output frequency range of 137.5 MHz to 4400 MHz. The reason why I'm proposing it is because to try and get a UHF/microwave oscillator set up with a variable capacitor or inductor is a nightmare - just bringing your hand close will shift it possibly tens of MHz.

It needs to be digitally controlled via something like a PIC and this overcomes most of the problems of drift and accuracy.